# NetBeans - button select database else if

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, xampp

I want to call id and password in database use button in netbeans, so I did like this

```
private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    try {
        String sql="select *from login where ID = '"+id.getText()+"'and Password = '"+String.valueOf(pass.getPassword())+"'and Status ='"+pilih1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'";
        ResultSet rss1=st.executeQuery(sql);
        if ((rss1.next())&&(pilih1.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Pasien")){
            pasien1 = new pasien1();
            pasien1.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
            System.out.println("haha");
        }
        else if ((rss1.next())&&(pilih1.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Dokter")){
            dokter1 = new dokter1();
            dokter1.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        }
        else if ((rss1.next())&&(pilih1.getSelectedItem().toString() == "Staff")){
            staff1 = new staff1();
            staff1.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gagal Login");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Terjadi Kesalahan");
    }

}
```

this source code can compile i don't have error
but why this code can only executed if and else and can't execute else if
give solution . . .

Comment: google for string comparison in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major issues here:

1. `String`s in Java are objects, so they need to be compared with the `equals` method, not the `==` operator, which checks object **identity**, not **equality**.
2. Calling `ResultSet.next()` will advance the cursor, so you should do it **before** the if-else structure. In the current code, the cursor will be advanced every time one of the conditions is evaluated, which is not the behavior you want to aheive.

In short:

```
ResultSet rss1=st.executeQuery(sql);
boolean hasResults = rss1.next()
if (hasResults && pilih1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Pasien")) {
    pasien1 = new pasien1();
    pasien1.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
    System.out.println("haha");
}
else if (hasResults && pilih1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Dokter")) {
    dokter1 = new dokter1();
    dokter1.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}
else if (hasResults && pilih1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Staff")){
    staff1 = new staff1();
    staff1.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}
else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gagal Login");
}
```